# How to dynamically define struct elements in C

Tags: c, loops, file, struct, memory-management

I want to create elements from the struct that I created as many as the number to be found in the program. Here is my code:

```
struct students {
    int studentNumber;
    char studentName[50];
    char studentSurname[50];
};
```

```
while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fstudent) != NULL) {
        number_of_students++;                                           //Number of students number has been founded!
    }
```

When I find my student count in the "While" structure, how do I generate that number of elements?

Comment: You don’t. You should define a struct for a student and then create an array or list of those structs

Comment: @pm100 I already defined a  struct for student. My question is how can I create its elements depending on number_of_students

Comment: You mean you want to increase the array of structs by one element each time you are in the loop? Or you mean you want to assign it after the loop?

Comment: Use malloc? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/

Comment: Why have you got a student struct and a students struct with arrays of student names, that makes zero sense

Comment: @pm100 I think you are confused. Despite the plural name, the students struct appears to contain one name and is for one student.

Comment: @EdmCoff Ok let me try again. I have a file with student information in it. Inside While I find how many students are in this file. Later, I want to create them as struct elements so that I can do operations on these students. As an example, let's say there are 3 students in the file. After running the while, we got number_of_students = 3. After that I want to create 3 students from struct students as s1, s2, s3. Here's how do I do that?

Comment: @pm100 Ok let me try again. I have a file with student information in it. Inside While I find how many students are in this file. Later, I want to create them as struct elements so that I can do operations on these students. As an example, let's say there are 3 students in the file. After running the while, we got number_of_students = 3. After that I want to create 3 students from struct students as s1, s2, s3. Here's how do I do that?

Comment: @pm100 sample students.txt file : https://imgur.com/a/KKGWKdC

Comment: As noted above, you can use malloc like `struct students *the_students = malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(struct students))` (don't forget to `free` it when you're done with it). If you're using C99, you can also do `struct students the_students[number_of_students]`

Comment: @RohanKumar I know how to use malloc but when I try it it gives me errors that I didint understand. Can u write an example depending on my structure and number_of_students ?

Comment: Please post the actual thing you tried and the actual error you got.

Comment: @EdmCoff Hell yea! I tried it but it didn't worked before. But now everything is ok. Thank u man!

Comment: @GençYazılımcı I'm glad it worked, but I hope you realize if you had posted what you actually tried and the error you had, you probably would have got the answer quicker (and probably would have received an explanation of what went wrong with your attempt).

Comment: @EdmCoff Ok dude ty for all. Next time I'll do it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use malloc for dynamic memory allocation. struct students *the_students = malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(struct students))